# How to run scripts automatically after deployment in AWS using EB CLI?

Tags: apache, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, wsgi

I am trying to make a Django server on AWS. My django app depends on some mathematical python libraries like numpy, scipy, sklearn etc. However there is an issue for which I need to this after every deployment

```
sudo nano /etc/httpd/conf.d/wsgi.conf
---------------------------------------
add this line in the file
WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
---------------------------------------
sudo /etc/init.d/httpd reload
```

Basically I need "`WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}`" in my wsgi.conf file otherwise I get 504. I am using a Custom AMI built on top of Amazon Linux 2014 and I am using EB CLI for deployment. However whenever I deploy the wsgi.conf is reset and it does not contain the line that I have added previously and I need to manually SSH into the EC2 instance and do this task myself. It gives a overhead on every deployment and its also not feasible once we scale up (cloning or creating instances also resets it). So is there a way that this will be automatically done after every deployment ?

The content of the wsgi.conf is fixed, so basically I can make a script easily to create it but the issue is how to trigger the script automatically ?

PS:I am new to AWS

Comment: Have you tried using .ebextensions and commands? http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html#customize-containers-format-commands

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use AWS Elastic Beanstalk feature called .ebextensions: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html

In your case you can't use *Files* or *Commands* sections, because:

> The commands are processed in alphabetical order by name, and they run
>   **before** the application and web server are set up and the application
>   version file is extracted.

You need to use *Container_commands* section:

> They run **after** the application and web server have been set up and the
>   application version file has been extracted, but before the
>   application version is deployed.

Example **.ebextensions/01wsgi.config** (not tested :-))

```
container_commands:

  apache_reload:
    command: |
      echo "WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}" >> /etc/httpd/conf.d/wsgi.conf
      /etc/init.d/httpd reload
```

Feel free to tweak my example as you want, for example you can copy your temporary wsgi.conf file somewhere and then replace original in *Container_commands* section.